British crime movie where a man is afraid to fall asleep?
In the movie one of the lead characters (an older man) thinks he is cursed and will die the next time he falls asleep (I think his previous dream predicted it). He resorts to drinking copious amounts of coffee and even eating coffee grinds to stay awake. In the end he still falls asleep, but doesn't die (IIRC).
Unfortunately I can't remember anything else about the movie, just that it was super funny (British black humour done right).
I would guess it was released in the early 2000s, as I saw it on a satellite TV movie channel in ~2010 or perhaps a bit earlier.
Hopefully someone can help me with this!

When was it released (approximately)?

I would guess early 2000s. I think I saw it in ~2010 (maybe earlier) from a paid satellite TV movie channel (which usually had quite a few recent movies on). I'll edit the question accordingly.

Sounds like you're after the Irish crime comedy Perrier's Bounty from 2009 starring Cillian Murphy, Jodie Whittaker and Brendan Gleeson.

Michael is a perpetual waster. He owes money to Perrier, a local thug. When two enforcers demand payment by nightfall, Michael does a burglary with two others but won't be paid till morning. All he has to do is stay away from the thugs until he can get the money then give it to Perrier. But the lads catch Michael and start to deliver a beating, but Brenda, Michael's suicidal neighbor, shoots one. Now they must run for their lives, accompanied by Jim, Michael's estranged father who claims to be dying and has come to reconcile with his son. Will any of the trio see the sun rise? And can Michael become enlightened, become a better man?

The protagonist's father (played by Jim Broadbent) claims that he saw the Grim Reaper in a dream and believes he'll die if he falls asleep, so he tries to stay awake using several methods - one of which is eating coffee straight out of the jar, which you can see in the trailer around 0:45:



